# Show that if $C[0,1]$ is equipped with the one-norm $||f||_1 =\int^1_0 |f(t)| dt $ then $δ : C[0, 1] → \Bbb R$ is an unbounded operator

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C[0, 1]$ be the linear space of all continuous functions on the interval $[0, 1]$. Let $δ : C[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$
be the linear functional that evaluates a function at the origin, that is, $δ(f) = f(0)$.

a) Show that if $C([0; 1])$ is equipped with the norm $||f|| = max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)|$, then $δ$ is
bounded and compute its norm $||δ||$.

b) Show that if $C([0; 1])$ is equipped with the one-norm
$$||f||_1 =\int^1_0 |f(t)| dt $$
then $δ$ is unbounded.

Proof idea (a):
Since $max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)|=M<\infty$,

$0\leq ||\delta||=sup_{||f||\neq0} \frac{||\delta f||}{||f||}=sup_{||f||\neq0} \frac{max|f(0)|}{max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)|}=|f(0)|\frac{1}{max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)|}\leq |f(0)|\frac{2}{M}$ so is bounded.

(b)

$||\delta||=sup \frac{||\delta f||}{||f||}sup \frac{|\int^1_0 |f(0)| dt|}{\int^1_0 |f(t)| dt}=|f(0)|sup\frac{1}{\int^1_0 |f(t)| dt}=...$

Now if I can find a function $f$ such that integrated between 0 and 1 is $F(1)-F(0)=0$,  all is well. Or, $f(t)=1/t$ then $F(t) = ln(t)$ and the integral with bounds 0 and 1 is divergent. Am I on the right track?
Thanks and Regards,

Comment: To cleanup a):  let $f=1$ then $||f||=1$ and $\delta(f)=1$ and $||\delta(f)||=1$. $||\delta||= sup\frac{||\delta(f)||}{||f||} \geq \frac{1}{1}=1$. Also $||\delta||=sup\frac{||\delta(f)||}{||f||}=sup\frac{f(0)}{max|f|}\leq sup\frac{max|f|)}{max|f|}=1$ so $||\delta||=1$

Comment: $0\leq \delta f=max|f(0)|=M< \infty$ since $f$ is continuous on closed interval. This means it is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to come up with continuous functions $f$ , so you cannot use $\frac 1 t$.

If $f_n(x)=1-nx$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 1  n$ and $0$ for $\frac  1n \leq x \leq 1$ then $\int_0^{1} |f_n(t)|dt \to 0$ but $\delta (f_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Could use the same function for a) to show that $||\delta||=1$? or should I use  $f_n(x)=n-nx$ for $1-1/n\leq x\leq 1$ and $f_n(x)=1$ for $0\leq x < 1-1/n$

Comment: If you are talking about part a) then you can take $f(x)\equiv 1$ to show that $\|\delta\|=1$. @Mihai.Mehe