# Prove linear operator on normed linear space is not continuous

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

$Q) \ C[0,1]=\{ \ f:[0,1]\rightarrow C$ such that$f$ is continuous $\}$ is a normed linear space with the norm

$\lVert f\rVert =\int_0 ^1|f| $. Prove that the map $\phi:C[0,1]\rightarrow C$ given by $\phi(f)=f(1)$ is not continuous.

I was planning on using the theorem that a linear function from one normed linear space(NLS) to another is continuous if and only if it is bounded i.e. its norm is less than $\infty$. I know the norm of a linear operator between two NLS is defined by

$$\lVert \phi \rVert= \sup\{ \lVert \phi(f)\rVert: \lVert f\rVert=1\}=\sup\{\lVert \phi(f)\rVert: \lVert f\rVert \leq 1\}=\sup\left\{ \frac{\lVert \phi(f)\rVert}{\lVert f\rVert}: \lVert f\rVert \neq 0 \right\}.$$

I was thinking that I could show the set is unbounded by introducing a sequence of function $f_n$
for which $ \ ||f_n||=1$ such that { $||\phi(f_n)||$ } is unbounded but couldn't find one. Can someone please help ? Is this the right method ?

Another property of linear operators between NLS which could be used is the fact that

$$\lVert \phi(f)\rVert \leq \lVert \phi\rVert \cdot \lVert f\rVert \ \forall f \in C[0,1].$$ So if we could show that there is no such real numbe$||\phi||$ then we can prove that $\phi $is unbounced linear opeator.

Comment: What is $||\phi(f)|| $ for your map $\phi$?

Comment: Yes, this is a good way of going about it. Don't worry too much if $\|f_n\|$ isn't always $1$ either; so long as $\|f_n\|$ is bounded above. The trick to finding such $f_n$ lies in exploiting how the norm is a measure of "area", not "height". You can make $f_n$ grow as large as you want at a single point, so long as the region becomes "thinner" to match (think: a rectangle with height $\alpha$ and width $1/\alpha$ has constant area $1$, no matter how large $\alpha$ gets). Try thinking about spiky piecewise linear functions that exploit this fact about area.

Comment: This question is same as  (part b) of) the following except for a trivial modification: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309326/show-that-if-c0-1-is-equipped-with-the-one-norm-f-1-int1-0-ft-dt/4309328#4309328

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce functions that are constant 0 at the beginning of $[0,1]$ and at the end there is a very short, very steep linear piece.
The integral then gives the area of a triangle. We want this area to be 1 for all $f_n$. The tip of the triangle should be at $x=1$ with height $f_n(1) = n$. The base of the triangle should therefore have length $\frac{2}{n}$. This way the area will become $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot n=1$. We search a linear function $g_n(x)=mx+b$ that satisfies $g_n(1-\tfrac{2}{n}) = 0, g_n(1) = n$. We solve this and obtain $g_n(x) = \frac{n^2}{2}x+n-\frac{n^2}{2}$. We may thus construct continuous functions
$$
f_n\colon\ [0,1]\to\mathbb R,\ x\mapsto \begin{cases}0 &\text{for}\ x \in [0, 1-\frac{2}{n}], \\ \frac{n^2}{2}x+n-\frac{n^2}{2} &\text{for}\ x\in [1-\frac{2}{n}, 1]\end{cases}.
$$
Now $\|f_n\| = \int_{[0,1]} f_n(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdot n = 1$ and $\phi(f_n)=n\to\infty$. Hence $\|\phi\|_{op}=\infty$.